# Why can't I edit layers created with DBManager?

Tags: qgis

I noticed a strange behavior in layers created with DB manager. 
Tested it in QGIS 2.6.1 and QGIS 2.12.0

In QGIS 2.6.1.
When i create a layer based on a sql query with the setting "Avoid selecting by feature id" turned off, i cannot start editing session on this new layer. The "start editing" button is inactive.
When i create a layer based on the same sql query with "Avoid selecting by feature id" turned on, the editing button in QGIS gets activated, i can start editing session but "Add feature" and "Save layer edits" buttons stay inactive. I can move any features or nodes on a feature, but still i cannot save the edits.

In QGIS 2.12.0
There is no difference, if i set "Avoid selecting by feature id" on or off, editing button is inactive and i cannot start editing session.

Is it a bug, am i doing something wrong or is QGIS ment to behave like this?
And what is this "Avoid selecting by feature id" option for?

O, and the data i want to edit comes from a PostGis database.

Comment: What type of layer are you using?

Comment: I am trying to edit vector layers. There's no significant difference, whether its points, lines or polygon features.

Comment: Oh I meant format type. Shp?

Comment: No, data is in PostGIS.

Comment: And the PostGIS-database is set with the extensions topology and tiger?

Comment: I have no use for the tiger extension, so tiger functionality is not added. postgis_topology extension is present. Not sure though, how these two could affect adding PostGis layers...

Answer (score 1):

I posted a bug report and got this response:
"Avoid selecting by feature id" option is not related to editing capabilities of a layer loaded from query. Apparently it was a bug in QGIS 2.6, but got fixed.
The layers loaded from querys are handled as views, so they are not supposed to be editable. 
Good to know.